# Artifactory and Jenkins - get file with newest/biggest custom property

Tags: jenkins, properties, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I have generic repository "my_repo". I uploaded files there from jenkins with to paths like my_repo/branch_buildNumber/package.tar.gz and with custom property "tag" like "1.9.0","1.10.0" etc. I want to get item/file with latest/newest tag.

I tried to modify Example 2 from this link ...
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs#UsingFileSpecs-Examples

... and add sorting and limit the way it was done here ...
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-limitDisplayLimitsandPagination

But im getting "unknown property desc" error.

[image: jenkins code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing and experimenting i found that there are many ways of solving my main problem (getting latest version of package) but each of way require some function which is available in paid version. Like sort() in AQL or [RELEASE] in REST API. But i found that i still can get JSON with a full list of files and its properties. I can also download each single file. This led me to solution with simple python script. I can't publish whole but only the core which should bu fairly obvious

```
import requests, argparse
from packaging import version

...

query="""
items.find({
  "type" : "file",
  "$and":[{
    "repo" : {"$match" : \"""" + args.repository +  """\"}, 
    "path" : {"$match" :  \"""" + args.path +  """\"} 
    }]
}).include("name","repo","path","size","property.*")
"""       
auth=(args.username,args.password) 


def clearVersion(ver: str):
    new = ''
    for letter in ver:
        if letter.isnumeric() or letter == ".":
            new+=letter
    return new

def lastestArtifact(response: requests):
    response = response.json()
    latestVer = "0.0.0"
    currentItemIndex = 0
    chosenItemIndex = 0
    for results in response["results"]:
        for prop in results['properties']:
            if prop["key"] == "tag":
                if version.parse(clearVersion(prop["value"])) > version.parse(clearVersion(latestVer)):
                    latestVer = prop["value"]
                    chosenItemIndex = currentItemIndex 
        currentItemIndex += 1
    return response["results"][chosenItemIndex]

req = requests.post(url,data=query,auth=auth)
if args.verbose:
    print(req.text)

latest = lastestArtifact(req)
...
```

I just want to point that THIS IS NOT permanent solution. We just didnt want to buy license yet only because of one single problem. But if there will be more of such problems then we definetly buy PRO subscription.

Answer (score 2):

The Jenkins Artifactory Plugin, like most of the JFrog clients, supports File Specs for downloading and uploading generic files.
The File Specs schema is described [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs). When creating a File Spec for downloading files, you have the option of using the "pattern" property, which can include wildcards. For example, the following spec downloads all the zip files from the my-local-repo repository into the local froggy directory:

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "my-local-repo/*.zip",
            "target": "froggy/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Alternatively, you can use "aql" instead of "pattern". The following spec, provides the same result as the previous one:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "my-local-repo",
          "$or": [
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "path": {
                    "$match": "*"
                  },
                  "name": {
                    "$match": "*.zip"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "target": "froggy/"
    }
  ]
}
```

The allowed AQL syntax inside File Specs does not include everything the Artifactory Query Language allows. For examples, you can't use the "include" or "sort" clauses. These limitations were put in place, to make the response structure known and constant.

Sorting however is still available with File Specs, regardless of whether you choose to use "pattern" or "aql". It is supported throw the "sortBy", "sortOrder", "limit" and "offset" File Spec properties.
For example, the following File Spec, will download only the 3 largest zip file files:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "my-local-repo",
          "$or": [
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "path": {
                    "$match": "*"
                  },
                  "name": {
                    "$match": "*.zip"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "sortBy": ["size"],
      "sortOrder": "desc",
      "limit": 3,
      "target": "froggy/"
    }
  ]
}
```

And you can do the same with "pattern", instead of "aql":

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "my-local-repo/*.zip",
      "sortBy": ["size"],
      "sortOrder": "desc",
      "limit": 3,
      "target": "local/output/"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can read more about File Specs [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs).

(After answering this question here, we also updated the File Specs documentation with these examples).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That clears things a lot! What about properties - can they be used for sorting things or obtaining the artifact latest/highest property value?

Comment: No, sorting files according to properties is not supposed. You can only filter files according to properties.

Comment: But when i tried to add filtering in my script from my answer ( "query" variable) by adding property.tag instead property.* then it didnt work. I had to grab all properties and loop over them to find "tag" property.

Comment: @EyalBenMoshe do you know if there is a JFrog Jira ticket open to track adding the ability sort according to properties? This would be an extremely useful feature.